# Find symmetrical entries dataframe, if not delete entry

Tags: pandas

I have the following data.

```
ID1 ID2 Value
1    2   5.5
2    1    10
1    3    5
```

Expected output:

```
ID1 ID2 Value
1    2   5.5
2    1    10
```

I only want to hold data, when I have a value for the symmetrical entry. If I only have a entry e.g. with ID1=1 and ID2=3 but no entry for ID1=3 and ID2=1 then I want to delete this datarow. How can I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all values in pairs in columns `ID1` and `ID2` are unique first create helper `DataFrame` with `np.sort` and return all duplicated rows with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['ID1','ID2']], axis=1), index=df.index)

df = df[df1.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df)
   ID1  ID2  Value
0    1    2    5.5
1    2    1   10.0
```

Comment: Thx it works well. I'm note sure if this is "appropiate" for stackoverflow: I don't quite understand what you do. I understand that you are doing a boolean comparison to filter the data. Can you explain to me what you do with "df1.groupby([0,1])[0].transform('size') // 2"?

Comment: @Gesetzt - sorry, now  is simplify answer - return all duplicated of sorted `ID1` and `ID2`. Can yo utest it?